# Where should I put a shape drawable in my Android folders?

Tags: android

I have a `.xml` file representing a shape and 5 `drawable-***` folders (for hdpi, ldp, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi).

Since this is a shape, I assume I only need one copy? Should I create a folder called drawable and place it in there? Or do I need one copy of the shape in each of the resolution specific folders?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can have a `res/drawable` folder, i.e. no suffix.  It will be used for all resolutions.  You can also use the `-nodpi` suffix, see [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for details.

Comment: My version of Eclipse automatically generates a `res/drawable-nodpi` folder, so I use that (rather than creating a new `res/drawable` folder).

Comment: what about `drawable-anydpi` @JasonSankey?